# running cron.php in moodle

Tags: cron, cpanel, moodle

I am using a plugin in moodle that requires running cron. I manually run localhost/moodle/admin/cron.php and it worked. So my question is how can I run this script all the time and not manually. I read about C panel but I'm not sure how to use it.
Any advise is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to your cpanel on your host, then go to the cron options. It should also you how often you want the cron to run and a script to run.

The script is

```
usr/bin/php  /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null
```

If you choose to run every 15 minutes then you should see something like this after setting up cron.

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null
```

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Cron

Comment: I followed this:
Use the Moodle Cron package. The simplest way is to use this little package MoodleCron-Setup.exe, which makes this whole thing very easy by installing a small Windows service. Run it and forget about it! Is it enough? Now I don't have to worry about cron.php anymore? it will run all the time??